# Configure Result Sources to show only Sites and Webs with a specific text in the URL

Tags: sharepoint-online, query, result-source

Scenario:
I'm using SPO.

I need a Result source that returns only Sites and Webs that contain the the word "Program" in their title. So far, i've managed to get results by using

```
{searchTerms} contentclass:STS_Web contentclass:STS_Site
```

But when i add `Title:Program`
In my query string, i get no results.

How do I make my Results Source show all the sites and webs with "Program" in their title?

Added Question: Can i also configure my Results Source to show all sites and webs containing a specific list named "Board"